# Polite way to ride in the dark

Tags: lighting, etiquette, night-riding

Sometimes I ride in the park which has no light. There always are dog walkers, runners and other cyclists.
So, when I ride towards someone I have two options:

- dim my light and slow down (since I can't go fast anymore)
- speed up to to minimize time that I light on those people

My front light is: [image: like this]

So, the question is: how to be less irritating?

Comment: That kid of light is there to make you visible. Therefore it accomplish it purpose. It is not like a strong car beam you are not blinding any one.

Comment: Well, this light can be kind of blinding in total darkness

Comment: I put my hand over the light to shade it for the last few metres when they've clearly seen me

Comment: Your headlight should be pointed down anyway, to illuminate the roadway.

Comment: is your light blinking?

Comment: @njzk2 no. I mean - it can, but it's in steady beam mode while I'm riding that area

Comment: +1 for the polite part. I've had more than enough near-accidents as a pedestrian caused by crazy bike blinkenlights operated by inconsiderate riders.

Comment: Get/invent a bike light that automatically dims when it detects eyes or another light ;-)

Comment: My light has a clever design that cuts horizontally the upper flow, so I never illuminate a person higher than the waist, while still keeping a lot of the road lit. It also includes a few high pointing dim lights for visibility, but they aren't blinding.

Comment: Regarding irritation: blinking lights are incredibly irritating to me. I have to stop walking (and thinking) till they pass me by, because I cannot concentrate at all.

Comment: @Davidmh never knew such light even exist! Now trying to find one, thanks =)

Comment: @k102 I have a Bush&Muller, very high quality lights.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Consider how you feel when a fellow cyclist approaches you will full beam straight ahead. It's pretty blinding, even for a moment, and especially off-road when your eyes aren't used to it.

So in a park:

- Dim your light to its lowest setting (within reason).
- Put it on steady beam. Flashing is more visible but also more annoying and
  disorientating.
- Physically push it forwards/downwards so it's pointing towards the ground, not into anyone's face.

If you do this then it doesn't matter whether you illuminate pedestrians or for how long.

Comment: Blinking lights are actually forbidden in the Netherlands, and the light should always point downwards to help you see the road, while still allowing others to see you.

Comment: You have to ride in the parks in the Netherlands?

Comment: Pointing down will only have limited effects if the light has a symmetrical beam, which most "bike lights" do. A symmetrical beam means it disperses the light in all directions, pointing down will only limit some, but not all of the errant light.  Lights with horizontal cutoffs when set up properly will not shine light above about waist level so therefore do not blind.

Comment: Blinking lights are not necessarily more visible, and reduce the ability of others to judge your position and velocity. See [this](http://www.fietsberaad.nl/library/repository/bestanden/Eindrapport_Fietsverlichting.pdf) report (Dutch)

Comment: @StephanBijzitter They're also forbidden in Poland but it doesn't stop people from using them - which btw. is beyond my understanding, riding in darkness with a blinking light would be even harder, more annoying and confusing than just using the ambient light.

Comment: @Maurycy - that's no longer the case in Poland.

Comment: @Maurycy - source: http://isap.sejm.gov.pl/DetailsServlet?id=WDU20150000305 (page 38) - :(

Comment: @nuoritoveri I stand correct. I still think it's completely asinine and it annoys me a lot as a driver, but I guess they must've had a good reason to allow that.

Comment: @Maurycy They surely had _some_ reason, but I wouldn't be so sure if it was "good". Other countries had their reasons to forbid it.

Comment: This is bad advice for making use of bad hardware Hardware that's so dangerous that it's plain illegal in some countries. The only real fix is to use a light light that does not blind.

Answer (score 43):

There are now [many bike lights on the market](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?398520-2015-latest-hotness-in-cutoff-battery-lights) which have a shaped beam with a "horizontal cutoff" giving strong light onto the road or path, but much less above the horizon. When adjusted correctly these allow you to see where you're going without dazzling oncoming traffic or pedestrians.

[image: Ixon IQ shaped beam with horizontal cutoff]

I use a [Busch & Muller Ixon IQ](http://road.cc/content/review/52554-buschmuller-ixon-iq-light) (pictured), but [there are others](http://road.cc/content/review/26007-supernova-airstream-light).

The gold standard for road lighting that doesn't dazzle oncoming road users is [StVZO](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/stvzo-bike-lights/?image=1&type=gallery&gallery=1&embedded_slideshow=1). It's a German standard, but IMO sensible to use on roads and busy paths anywhere.

[image]
If you don't want to fork out for a new light, you can [make a hood for the light to block](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/28707/5337) the light from going upwards.

Comment: That’s the only good answer. A proper headlight will have a horizontal cut-off.

Comment: +1. A dipped light is the only polite light.

Answer (score 10):

I had to face exactly this on an old commute.  Dipping the front light was absolutely necessary in a park and another stretch of unlit bike path.  It was a bright enough light to illuminate the road, though not well enough to ride at any decent rate on low power.

The solution I found to this was to add a narrow-beam head torch.  This can be dipped hands free, and points where you look rather than where the bars are pointing (quite useful when it's pitch dark and you're next to a lake going round sharp bends).  Overhanging branches can mean the need to illuminate stuff that's not the road surface, so I tended to adjust the light as I rode much as you'd switch from main beams to dipped beams in a car.

The head torch I bought was ~5 from dealextreme, and is 150 lumens nominal -- so not very much ligfht in total.  But all that light is in a bike-sized area of road even if it's  directed 10 bike lengths away.  I tended to adjust the angle such that I had to tip my head slightly up to illuminate as far away as I'd like for ~30km/h speeds on imperfect tarmac, so that a natural head position was more suited to slower speeds with other people around.  In busy areas well-lit I could easily point it almost straight down.

Answer (score 9):

In case you can read German, [here's a nice explanation how to adjust the bike front light](http://fahrradbeleuchtung-info.de/fahrradscheinwerfer-richtig-einstellen).

Summary:

- put bike 5m from a wall
- measure distance (height) of the light from the street
- make sure that the upper rim of the light at 5m distance (wall) is below that height.
- Official German regulation: center of light beam should be at half height at 5 m distance = should hit the road at 10 m distance

Adjust speed according to visible range (just like when driving a car)

Comment: Downside of this is 10 metres is 2 seconds warning at 18 km/h.

Comment: @Criggie Yes, the German law is totally outdated in this regard, the prescriptions come from way back when bike lights were dynamo powered 6W heat bulbs that barely sufficed to produce a visible light patch on the ground. With modern LED lights and a sharp cutoff, the cutoff should be just a tad below horizontal, enabling 30m to 40m of perfect view on any pedestrians shoes. Yes, that's illegal in the strict sense of the law, but it's much better in the higher interest of riding safely.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it overlooks the fact that the OP's light does not seem to have a cutoff of the light cone. It's not even legal to use the OP's light in Germany, even though many people do so out of pure ignorance.

Answer (score 8):

You can dip the light slightly (point it towards the ground). Even without considering politeness, you might prefer to illuminate the ground ahead of you, instead of (as you would on a lit city street) pointing it straight forward to be seen as maximum distance.

Comment: The faster I go, the more far should I light - so dipping the light would lead me to slow down

Comment: Yes: slow down. I don't know whether you drive a car, but I am conscious that even on a bike I weigh 80 kg: if I run over a small animal I reckon I'd kill it -- politeness wants me to slow down when I can't see well. Also, a couple of times in my life I've noticed a dog or very small child run *towards* (into the path of) my bike ... fascinated by the light probably. Anyway, just point it 5 or 10 metres ahead of you, instead of straight ahead. You said the park is unlit, I think the light is useless to you (except as a warning to others) if it doesn't touch the ground at all.

Comment: The light is mounted waist-high, so it's below eye-height (unless the eyes are at ground-level). So to prevent light shining in the eye, simply ensure that the top of the bright (central) part of the light-beam is oriented to not shine upwards. That's what cars do with their head-lights, to avoid dazzling/blinding each other.

Comment: downvote for suggesting that it is ever appropriate to not aim the light down.  aiming horizontally on the streets actually worsens visibility due to dazzling others. lights don't need to be very bright to be seen from an extremely long distance, even in the city.

Comment: @Leliel I ride on an illuminated busy street with cars on it, and relatively few bikes. My light is definitely up in this case.

Comment: @Sparhawk not a good idea. Bright lights aimed at the eyes make it very easy to see that *something* exists. but almost impossible to see what or where. Both of these are kinda important to avoid hitting things

Comment: @Leliel You mention "bright", so I guess we're probably considering difference scenarios. If the light is not too bright, then I think it's fine to aim it up. Hence, I think that there in nothing wrong in general with aiming lights up in some situations (and thus disagree with the -1.)

Comment: @Sparhawk I disagree for two reasons. 1) What you consider bright may differ significantly from what I consider bright. My eyes adjust slower than normal to sudden changes in brightness, so I have a lot more trouble with dazzling than most. 2) In my area, many cyclists aim extremely bright lights at eyelevel (100+ lumen directional lights)

Comment: @Leliel I agree with you in theory, *if* the light is too bright. I'm talking about situations where the light is not too bright. If I were to point it down, then traffic would not see it. There is a range of brightness in lights. Below some arbitrary threshold, it seems reasonable to point lights up.

Comment: @Sparhawk in theory, you're right. In practice, many people pay no attention to brightness when aiming lights, so it makes sense to just discourage aiming high

Comment: @Leliel Theoretically you might not need a light at all, to be "seen from an extremely long distance", when the street is illuminated by street-lights. Nevertheless I want to be obvious (especially at intersections when people are busy, looking around). When I want to be seen my light is not especially bright, but I set it to [blinking](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/2295/1097): noticeable but not dazzling, IMO. When I want to use it to see (to illuminate the ground on an unlit path) then I set it to steady (and adjust the distance).

Answer (score 2):

Lights or not, when you're mixing with people walking, just go slow. I'd be much more annoyed to be overtaken at speed than to have a light shined on me, because your speed is an actual danger, and the light, at worst, an irritant.

Answer (score 1):

I wear an adjustable head strap flashlight at night while riding my bike. The one I have has three colors (white, red and green)which allows me to use a less intense color at times, so as not to blind people. As an addition to three colors, of has three level of intensity. It is worth looking into. With this you are able to turn your head slightly when needed.

[image: Adjustible head flashlight]

These [examples](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Hardware-Safety-Security-Flashlights-Accessories/Adjustable-Head-Strap/N-5yc1vZc24wZ1z0v1rd) may be of help to you. The one pictured is the style I use at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, the link is dead. Can you fix it?

Comment: And, conversely, you're able to blind people on the road by looking at them, since that causes your beam to point straight at them...

Comment: Colours will be dependent on location.  Here, red lights may only be used to the rear, and green or blue  lights are not permitted on vehicles at all.  Green is for emergency doctors (not ambos) and blue is reserved solely for police cars.

Answer (score 1):

> how to be less irritating?

Some countries have legal requirements around what makes for a good bike light, for example Germany.

Cheap lights are almost always:

- Powered by a very powerful battery capable of supplying a huge number of watts (to  cover up the fact that the light has a poor beam pattern and instead provide so many lumens that it seems bright enough)
- Have a flashlight-style reflector that is spherically symmetric, usually produced in China for flashlights but then someone decided to reuse the reflector for vehicle lights
- Mounted on the handlebar using a style of mount that is prone to changing the angle of the light if riding at high speed over bumps, instead of proper mounting hardware for fork crown that is held with tight bolts to keep the angle of the light fixed
- For extra points, have a blinking mode to save battery life and irritate other road users

These cheap lights are excellent in blinding oncoming people. The only possibility you can see forward is to direct the brightest part of the beam far away in the road. This means a large portion of the spherically symmetric pattern is projected above the horizon, blinding oncoming riders.

However, the cheap lights are usually poor for seeing because the beam pattern is not designed for road use. The spherical pattern directs too much light where not needed and too little light where needed.

The Germans have a solution for this: their **StVZO** laws require lights to be non-blinking, powered by a power source that doesn't suddenly go away (=dynamo), and the beam pattern to be such that it lights the road ahead of the cyclist and only the road ahead of the cyclist, having a sharp cut-off at the beam to not direct any part of the bright beam above the horizon (there will be still plenty of spill light that won't blind others but allows car drivers to see there's a bike).

Unfortunately quality costs. Only about 1% of people live in Germany, so pretty much the Germans are designing lights only for 1% of the population. If a German quality headlight manufacturer can amortize the product development costs of a true vehicle headlight over 1% of cyclists in this planet and a Chinese manufacturer can amortize the product "development" (in quotes because reusing flashlight technology doesn't really require any additional work) costs of a flashlight over 99% of cyclists in this planet, guess which light will be more expensive and which will be less expensive?

Comment: Generally a good answer, but I believe it could be improved: Parts of it sound more like a rant rather than an objective answer. People would trust your answer much more if you edited out the rantiness and replaced it with a more neutral, objective tone. - Btw: Afaik, dynamo lights are not required anymore. Battery lights have been made legal in Germany, but the other requirements like the cutoff and the prohibition of flashing lights remain.

Answer (score 0):

There are lights for illuminated streets and lights for rough terrain in the darkness. They best features are not the same. One case calls for low, narrow and not too bright beams, and in another such approach may just not illuminate your path if the turn is sharp enough or terrain is too rough.

- Many "wild terrain" lights are too bright for any more civilized route under they brightest setting and must be adjusted taking the sane mind into consideration. This remains true also when the brightest setting is default when turned on.
- Drivers would alert you when your lights seem not in order, by shortly switching the high beam on. Other cyclists may tell. Do something about your lights in such cases. Some pedestrians are very sensitive and may push unsafe setup so be more careful with they recommendations.
- Do not use the front flashing light.

This is probably the most that can be done. The highly shaped beam is actually dangerous in a wrong place, so probably not good to say you absolutely must have such a light, unless maybe it provides a separate "high beam" option. In any case, be sure first you always see far enough to stop, then think about politeness.